# Hypothesis in Lusin's Theorem

Tags: measure-theory

If $f\colon E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable function, and $m(E)<\infty$, then by Lusin's theorem, restriction of $f$ to a large closed set is continuous.

It is in the proof, I saw, that $m(E)<\infty$ is used along with Egorove's theorem.
If we drop the condition $m(E)<\infty$, then the usual proof will not work;  but I am not sure, whether there is other proof, which don't use the hypothesis $m(E)<\infty$, nor I could understand whether the condition $m(E)<\infty$ can't  be dropped.

**Question:** Is it necessary to consider $m(E)<\infty$ in Lusin's theorem?

Comment: If you can partition (cover) $E = \bigcup_n E_n$ with $m(E_n) < \infty$, then you can choose for each $n$ some subset $F_n \subset E_n$ with $m(E_n \setminus F_n) \leq \varepsilon \cdot 2^{-n}$ and $g_n : E_n \to \Bbb{R}$ continuous with $g_n = f$ on $F_n$. Then $m(E \setminus F) \leq \varepsilon$, where $F = \bigcup_n F_n$. You just have to find a way to "paste together" the individual pieces $(g_n)_n$ (so that the resulting $g$ is **continuous**, maybe by discarding some sets of small measure). To do this, it would be easiest to know something about $E$. Is $E \subset \Bbb{R}^n$?